# Need help with WCF EndpointNotFoundException TCP error code 10061

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, wshttpbinding

I'm a **WCF** noob, so I sincerely hope I'm doing something *obviously* wrong.  Still, I've looked all over and although there seems to be numerous errors similar to **TCP error code 10061**, they seem to apply to different scenarios.

All I'm trying to do here is **simply host a wsHttpBinding service from IIS**, and have a console app on that same server connect to the WCF service.  Any help makes you awesome in my eyes.  I've looked at so many help pages, I'm sort of *wrapped around the axle* at this point.  Thanks very much for your ideas and recommendations.  **Below is the error message** I get after running the console app.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
>   Could not connect to http://mysite.com/Service/MyService.svc.
>   TCP error code 10061: No connection
>   could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it .  --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to con
>   nect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>       at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,
>   Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&
>   exception)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to verify is: Can you browse to http://mysite.com/Service/MyService.svc ?

If that doesn't work your app has no hope of doing better.

**EDIT**

Second question: can you access it from the machine your app is running on with the user the app will be running under?
These may seem like silly questions, but with "weird issues" like this, ya gotta start at ground floor. Plus you didn't mention what you HAVE tried :).

Comment: I can definitely get to the service page and I can view the WSDL from the link there.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check that the ***Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service*** is enabled.